# I'm trying to figure it out how the option #2 cant run. C programming

Tags: c

my code is look like this:

```
int main(){
    int choice=(1,2,3);
    printf("1- Finabocci sequence\n");
    printf("2- Check valid date\n");
    printf("3- Quit\n");
    printf("Choose an operation: \n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch(choice){
    case 1:
    {
        int t1 = 0, t2 = 1, nextTerm = 0, n;
        printf("Enter a positive number: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("Fibonacci Series: %d, %d, ", t1, t2);
        nextTerm = t1 + t2;
        while(nextTerm <= n)
        {
            printf("%d, ",nextTerm);
            t1 = t2;
            t2 = nextTerm;
            nextTerm = t1 + t2;
        }
        break;
    }


    case 2:
    {
        int validDate(int d,int m,int y){
            if (m<1||m>12) return 0; 
            else if (m==1||m==3||m==5||m==7||m==8||m==10||m==12){
                if (d>=1&&d<=31) return 1; 
                else return 0;
            }
            else if (m==4||m==6||m==9||m==11) {
                if (d>=1&&d<=30) return 1; 
                else return 0;
            }  
            else if (m==2) {
                if (y%400==0||(y%4==0&&y%100!=0)) {
                    if (d>=1&&d<=29) return 1;
                    else return 0;
                }
                else if (d>=1&&d<=28) return 1;
                else return 0;
            }
        }


        int main(int validDate(int d,int m,int y)) {
            int d,m,y;
            printf ("Input day: ");
            scanf("%d",&d);
            printf ("Input month: ");
            scanf("%d",&m);
            printf ("Input year: ");
            scanf("%d",&y);
            if(validDate(d,m,y)!=0) printf("valid date");
            else printf("invalid date");
            return 0;
        } 
        break;
    }
    default: printf("exit?");
        getchar();
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

I'm not really know how the option2 is not running at all, like the 1st one and the 3rd are normal. How do i can fix this :D
For example: I'm running the Option2 code alone and its work, but when i put in the switch then its wont work at all

Comment: This doesn't look like valid C code.

Comment: You can't declare functions inside other functions. And you can't have two `main()` functions.

Comment: Some compilers allow declaring nested functions as an extension. But you never call the inner `main()` function, so it never calls `validDate()`.

Comment: There's no need for the nested functions. Just make case 2 like case 1: prompt for the inputs and perform the calculations with them.

Comment: thx mr.Barmar xd, i did fix my problem alr :"D. Preciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First thing is `int main(int validDate(int d,int m,int y))` should correct like this `int validDate(int d,int m,int y)`
- In your case these codes cannot be like this.

  `int choice=(1,2,3);` - wrong

  `int choice= 0;` - right
- other thing is

  1. `nextTerm = t1 + t2;`

     output -:`0,1,1,2,3` --> wrong
  2. `nextTerm = t2 + 1;`

     output -:`0,1,2,3` --> right
- Another thing is you have to put `break;` statement after every `cases` and `default` either when you compiling your code its compile every `cases` and `default` you have given
- Final thing is follow good coding methods. It also helps you to identify your errors

here the corrected code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int choice = 0;
    printf("1- Finabocci sequence\n");
    printf("2- Check valid date\n");
    printf("3- Quit\n");
    printf("Choose an operation: \n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            int t1 = 0, t2 = 1, nextTerm = 0, n;
            printf("Enter a positive number: ");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            printf("Fibonacci Series: %d, %d, ", t1, t2);
            nextTerm = t2 + 1;
            while(nextTerm <= n)
            {
                printf("%d, ",nextTerm);
                t1 = t2;
                t2 = nextTerm;
                nextTerm = t1 + t2;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            int validDate(int d,int m,int y)
            {
                if (m<1||m>12)
                     return 0; 
                else if (m==1||m==3||m==5||m==7||m==8||m==10||m==12)
                {
                    if (d>=1&&d<=31) 
                         return 1; 
                    else 
                        return 0;
                }
                else if (m==4||m==6||m==9||m==11) 
                {
                    if (d>=1&&d<=30) 
                        return 1; 
                    else 
                        return 0;
                }  
                else if (m==2)
                {
                    if (y%400==0||(y%4==0&&y%100!=0)) {
                        if (d>=1&&d<=29) 
                            return 1;
                        else 
                            return 0;
                }
                else if (d>=1&&d<=28) 
                    return 1;
                else 
                    return 0;
                }
            }

            int d,m,y;
            printf ("Input day: ");
            scanf("%d",&d);
            printf ("Input month: ");
            scanf("%d",&m);
            printf ("Input year: ");
            scanf("%d",&y);
            if(validDate(d,m,y)!=0) printf("valid date\n");
            else printf("invalid date \n");
            break;
        }
        default: printf("exit?");
                 break;
        getchar();
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling main fuction on main fuction. I fix the code for u.

```
int main(){
int choice=(1,2,3);
printf("1- Finabocci sequence\n");
printf("2- Check valid date\n");
printf("3- Quit\n");
printf("Choose an operation: \n");
scanf("%d", &choice);
switch(choice){
    case 1:
{
    int t1 = 0, t2 = 1, nextTerm = 0, n;
    printf("Enter a positive number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Fibonacci Series: %d, %d, ", t1, t2);
    nextTerm = t1 + t2;
    while(nextTerm <= n)
{
    printf("%d, ",nextTerm);
    t1 = t2;
    t2 = nextTerm;
    nextTerm = t1 + t2;
}
break;
}
case 2:
    {
       int validDate(int d,int m,int y){
    if (m<1||m>12) return 0; 
    else if (m==1||m==3||m==5||m==7||m==8||m==10||m==12){
    if (d>=1&&d<=31) return 1; 
    else return 0;
 }
 else if (m==4||m==6||m==9||m==11) {
    if (d>=1&&d<=30) return 1; 
    else return 0;
 }  
 else if (m==2) {
    if (y%400==0||(y%4==0&&y%100!=0)) {
        if (d>=1&&d<=29) return 1;
        else return 0;
         }
         else if (d>=1&&d<=28) return 1;
         else return 0;
        }
}

    int d,m,y;
    printf ("Input day: ");
    scanf("%d",&d);
    printf ("Input month: ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf ("Input year: ");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    if(validDate(d,m,y)!=0) printf("valid date\n");
    else printf("invalid date \n");

}
     default: printf("exit?");
     getchar();
 }
    return 0; 
}
```